# How can I make random numbers that never repeat in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
int[] sayısal = new int[6];
Random rastgele = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   do
   {
      sayısal = rastgele.Next(1, 50);
   }
   while (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(sayısal) != -1);
      listBox1.Items.Add(sayısal);
}
```

When I did like this, I take an error that calls

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]' "

in line `"sayısal = rastgele.Next(1, 50);"`. What can I do for it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please be much more careful about formatting next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate sequence `1..50` and shuffle it (i.e. sort by random value):

```
Random rastgele = new Random();
int[] sayısal = Enumerable.Range(1, 50) // generate sequence
                          .OrderBy(i => rastgele.Next()) // shuffle
                          .Take(6) // if you need only 6 numbers
                          .ToArray(); // convert to array
```

---

Your code is not working, because you are trying to assign generated item to array variable.

```
sayısal = rastgele.Next(1, 50);
```

It should be instead:

```
do {
   sayısal[i] = rastgele.Next(1, 50);
} while(listBox1.Items.IndexOf(sayısal[i]) != -1);
```

---

As I already pointed in comments, it's better to separate UI logic and array generation. I.e.

```
// generate array (optionally move to separate method)
int itemsCount = 6;
int[] items = new int[itemsCount]; // consider to use List<int>
Random random = new Random();
int item;

for(int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
{
   do {
      item = random.Next(1, 50);
   } while(Array.IndexOf(items, item) >= 0);

   items[i] = item;
}

// display generated items
listBox1.Items.Clear();
for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) // or use foreach
    listBox1.Items.Add(items[i]);
```

Comment: I got what you mean but there is also an error in "Array.IndexOf(item)" and "listBox1.Items.AddRange(items);". I'm very glad for your help. I'm not good at C#, I cant understand these errors.

Comment: When I did it like this, I can insert the random numbers but it can repeat same numbers. 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            int[] sayi = new int[6];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(rnd.Next(10, 50).ToString());


            }
        }

Comment: @user3052898 sorry, updated code (I haven't used VS when I posted it, so some compiler errors leaked out)

Answer (score 2):

Because [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns an `int`, not `int[]`. And there is no implicit conersation from `int[]` to `int`.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Int32
A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.
```

If you want to fill your array, you can use `Enumerable.Range` like *[lazyberezovsky mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20304689/447156)*.

Comment: Also correct answer :) I also think that getting index of array in listbox also not very nice idea :)

Comment: I'm learning C# at this time and our teacher wanted us to make it. I searched almost everywhere but I couldnt find anything.

Comment: @user3052898 I suggest you to separate array generation and displaying items on UI. I.e. generate array without referencing listbox

Comment: @user3052898 Take a look at [lazyberezovsky's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20304689/447156) then?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky He might get a BrainOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

This method takes an integer array and randomly sorts them. 
So fill an array with a loop then use this to randomly sort the array.
You should credit one of the others as they were first to post with valid answers. I just thought another way to do this would be good.

amount is the amount of times you want the array to randomize. The higher the number the higher the chance of numbers being random.

```
    private Random random = new Random();

    private int[] randomizeArray(int[] i, int amount)
    {
        int L = i.Length - 1;
        int c = 0;
        int r = random.Next(amount);
        int prev = 0;
        int current = 0;
        int temp;

        while (c < r)
        {
            current = random.Next(0, L);
            if (current != prev)
            {
                temp = i[prev];
                i[prev] = i[current];
                i[current] = temp;
                c++;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful in your choice of data structures and algorithms, pick the wrong one and you'll wind up with O(n^2). A reasonable solution IMHO is a typed hash table (i.e. dictionary) which will give you O(n):

```
Random rnd = new Random();              
        var numbers = Enumerable
            .Range(1, 1000000)
            .Aggregate(new Dictionary<int, int>(), (a, b) => {
                int val;
                do {val = rnd.Next();} while (a.ContainsKey(val));
                a.Add(val, val);
                return a;
            })
            .Values
            .ToArray();
```

Still not ideal though as performance depends on the array size being significantly smaller than the set of available numbers and there's no way to detect when this condition isn't met (or worse yet when it's greater, in which case the algorithm will go into an infinite loop).